# UNIX: error when I try to use array

Tags: regex, bash, shell, unix

I have this code and when I try it in FreeBSD it shows me a lot of errors... how can I fix it? I check directories, if it match with variable IGN. NAME_d should be an array.

```
max_d=$(find "${DIR}" -type d | wc -l)

for i in `seq 1 $max_d`
do
  check_d=$(find "${DIR}" -type d | head -n "${i}" | tail -n -1 | tr '\/' '\n' | egrep -n "${IGN}")

  if [ ! -z "$check_d" ]; then

    NAME_d+=$i"d "

  fi

done

directory_d=${NAME_d[*]}
sedCmds_d=${directory_d// /;}
```

[image: erroe]

Comment: this is the second time today I see this `seq` loop with a previous find and another find in the loop reading only one line from each find. This is far from optimal. Rethink your work! How about `let x=0; find . -type d | while read dir; do let 'x++'; DO YOUR WORK WITH $dir HERE, POSSIBLY ALSO USING LINENO $x.; done`

Comment: You don't appear to be using `bash`, which has allowed `+=` for assignment statements since version 3.1. In addition, `NAME_d` is not an array even if you were using `bash`.

Comment: Provide information as image iff they can't be posted as text (readable, searchable, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays are a bashism not supported by the Almquist shell, the default bourne style shell on FreeBSD (i.e. /bin/sh). An advantage of the shell is that most scripts run about 3 times faster.

If you want to use bashisms, use bash to execute your script. E.g. call it `bash dirstat.sh` or change the shebang.

This is the correct one for FreeBSD.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash
```

This is the portable version but requires PATH to be set:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

You also might have to install bash first: `pkg add bash`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it will solve it, but if you're using bash, you should initiate NAME_d as an array

```
NAME_d=()
```

and then adding to the array you should also use parens, e.g.

```
NAME_d+=("${i}d ")
```